# Derivative of sinx from first principle

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I am just confused over this step in the derivative of sin x

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin\left(x\right) \over x} = 1
$$

- When we have the limit, my textbook uses the small angle approximations, to say $\sin\left(x\right) \approx x$ for small $x$ in radians.
- However, how is it that we can simply replace $\sin\left(x\right)$ with $x$, and keep the limit still there, surely we must have taken the limit to reach the conclusion that $\sin\left(x\right) \approx x$, and thus we cannot keep the limit there, as we have already applied $\mbox{it}~?$.

The limit is kept there to reach the conclusion it equals $1$.

Comment: Seems a little circular.  What book are you using?

Comment: Edexcel A Level Mathematics Pure year 2

Comment: The standard approach is to use the squeeze theorem and an inequality using areas of part of a circle and some related triangle areas. Here's a video going over it https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-limits-new/ab-1-8/v/sinx-over-x-as-x-approaches-0

Comment: No it is not like this that it works : it should be considered as a consequence of this classical "squeezing" $\forall x \in (0,\pi/2), \sin x <x<\ \tan x \implies (\sin x/x) <1<(\sin x/x) \times (1/\cos x) \implies \cos x < (\sin x/x)<1$ where the second double inequality comes from division by $x$. Now let $x \to 0_+$.

Comment: Thanks for your guys help

Comment: [MSE $\tt MathJax$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).